# Getting the data from the resolver in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, resolver

I want to get some data from the resolver after I do some filtering with the data I get from the backend. Everything works fine with getting the data from the backend and filtering it, but the problem is that I cannot return the final data so I can get it into the component, Please see below my code:

Resolver:

```
resolve = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> => {
    let routeObjKeys = Object.keys(route.params);
    let jobApplicationsArray = [];
    if(routeObjKeys.length !== 0) {
      let response = this.jobApplicationsService.getJobApplications('', 0, 100, 'firstName', 'ASC').subscribe(data => {
        routeObjKeys.forEach(function(key) {
          jobApplicationsArray.push(data["data"].filter(jobApp => jobApp.id === route.params[key])[0]);
        });
        console.log("jobApplicationsArray: ", jobApplicationsArray);
        return jobApplicationsArray;
      });
      return Observable.of(response);
    } else {
      return this.jobApplicationsService.getJobApplications('', 0, 10, 'firstName', 'ASC');
    }

  }
```

Component:

```
getResolverData = () => {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {  // Get the data from the resolver
        console.log('jobApplications from component: ', data);
      });
  }
```

Into the resolver, the `jobApplicationsArray` array contains the filtered data, but in the component it is undefined, so I think I don't return it properly from the resolver. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to debug in your resolver. Use console.log() in both of your return cases and check whether you reach one of these points and what the returned value looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using `map` instead of `subscribe`, so I returned an Observable instead of a Subscriber:

```
resolve = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> => {
    let routeObjKeys = Object.keys(route.params);
    let jobApplicationsArray = [];
    if(routeObjKeys.length !== 0) {
      return this.jobApplicationsService.getJobApplications('', 0, 100, 'firstName', 'ASC').map(data => {
        routeObjKeys.forEach(function(key) {
          jobApplicationsArray.push(data["data"].filter(jobApp => jobApp.id === route.params[key])[0]);
        });
        return jobApplicationsArray;
      });
    } else {
      return this.jobApplicationsService.getJobApplications('', 0, 10, 'firstName', 'ASC');
    }
  }
```